# Nested div styling offset

Tags: html, css

I have a div container with position set to fixed. When I try to add content within this div tag, the content begins at the bottom of the tag and not at the top.

```
#toolbox{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 1;
}
#secondary{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 10px;
    width:10px;
}
```

My html looks like

```
<div id="toolbox">
     <span id="secondary">Test</span>
</div>
```

The text 'Test' comes towards the bottom of the toolbox. And if I add multiple elements like radio buttons or another div tags (and set overflow to auto in toolbox) the elements form a big page within the toolbox itself.

Adding Source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Crisper</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body onload="start()">
    <header>
        <h1>Test Util</h1>

        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
    </header>
    <hr>

    <div id="dropbox">
        <div id="toolbox">
            <span id="secondary">Res</span>
        </div>
        <img id="canvas" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" >
    </div>

    <hr>
    <footer>
        <button id="download-butotn">Download</button>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#dropbox {
    min-height: 70%;
    text-align: center; 
}

img{
    min-height: 500px;
    min-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
}

#toolbox{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index: 1;

}

#secondary{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[image: This is what is seen on my local machine]

Comment: Not according to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32gyhd3b/

Comment: Cannot reproduce. https://jsfiddle.net/9azmf2cq/

Comment: I think your problem is some where else! It has not the problem you say. Remove `top: 250px` and test the result.

Comment: Since it doesn't do that in the posted code, we can't help you

Comment: @FarzinKanzi, I have tried this. Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting line height through javascript which was causing the offset. Simply overriding the value of the line height attribute in the CSS file again does the job.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possible reasons for it. However, the code you provided does not include any. Here are a few common ones:

1. It has `bottom: 0;`
2. It has a set `height` and display rules making its children align to bottom
   (i.e.: `display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content: flex-end;`)
3. It has  `padding-top`, `margin-top` or `top`.

**Note 1:** The most probable cause is **1.**
**Note 2:** There are multiple other ways to align children to bottom  inside a tall parent. (**2.**)

---

If none of the above help, you have to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: There is more, like `display:flex;align-items: flex-end; `, `column-reverse`, `vertical-align` etc., so the list is quit long

Comment: The weird part is that even if i copy pasted my code on fiddle, it does not reproduce. Seen on local machine however

Comment: May I ask why you post an answer with a lot of guessing? ... You've been around way to long to do that

Comment: Of course you may, @LGSon. I did it for the same reason I answer any other question on SO: with the hope it helps OP and future users with the same problem. As per ways to align children on bottom, I did specify there are numerous other ways to do it. The most probable cause, though, IMHO is 1), foloowed by 3), than 2).

Comment: So what about SO's policy with having proper asked questions? ... Answering questions like this is not good, since it is a bad one not even reproduce the issue described

Comment: Sorry but this is not appropriate to just through out a guess like that. Then we all could just drop answers that could solve a part of any question, just to be nice?? ... Nope, and since there is so many more missing, it will be a down vote from me

Comment: I completely understand and agree, @LGSon. In theory, you are right. In practice, I thought I could lend a helping hand to someone who clearly has less practice in working with `CSS`.

Comment: @LGSon, there's something I need to ask you as well. You down-voted my answer based on the low quality of the question and, in principle, I agree with our vote. But why haven't you down-voted the question? I'm not urging you to do it, to me it's clear they read [ask] and they tried to provide some code to help debug. In the end, the OP's problem is they're not able to reproduce the described behavior, never-mind pinpoint the cause (and this is a real problem for novice programmers). Their only other option is to learn `CSS` which does not happen over night.

Comment: I more or less always discuss with the poster (questioner or answerer) before down voting, to get to know their reason. If I still think it is wrong and they do things against SO policy (how interpret it), then I down vote. Regarding this question, the poster has been asked to update, hence I wait a little bit. In your case, you replied straight away, so no need to wait. Also, when throwing answers like you did, and if the poster find anything in your answer, that might helped them, what good does that do for future users? ... No where is any explanation what actually solved it

Comment: So I down voted because I don't think we should encourage to post answers like that, on incomplete questions, since their is little, if any, good for future users, I believe an answer should address a specific question, not a random answer that could be applied to many. Also, I can't see the educational value in such answer either, since the solutions you provided were not that well explained.

Comment: As you might have guessed, it's not the first time I try to help novice programmers like this, even though it's not in accordance with the ideal principles outlined in [answer] and [ask]. But, from experience, I can tell you the outcome is positive. They usually say what worked. And as far as usefulness to future visitors, I benefited from answers enumerating causes for difficult to pinpoint problems. In principle, you're right. In practice, it's at least debatable. I do hope it will help future users chancing by. It should be renamed, though for better indexing. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: For your info, I brought this up on meta: [provide-an-answer-with-an-educational-purpose-to-an-incomplete-kind-of-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348494/provide-an-answer-with-an-educational-purpose-to-an-incomplete-kind-of-questio)

Comment: @LGSon: Now I need to leave it open, so your question makes sense. And I'll be the target of a lot of down-votes. Well, let's see what comes out of it... :)

Comment: Sorry about that :) ... As I can see both good and bad in the way you replied, I wanted to know what the community in general says. And you can always either delete it later, or make it a wiki, and save the reps. :)

Comment: Don't worry about it, man. If I was on [so] for the rep I'd have been gone long time now.